# Solving a single variable equation

Tags: linear-algebra

can someone help me in seperating x in the below equation?$$\frac{x-x_l}{\sqrt{(x-x_l)^2+y_l^2}} = f*\frac{x-x_w}{\sqrt{(x-x_w)^2+y_w^2}}$$ $$x_l, x_w, y_l, y_w, f\ are \ constants $$

I am trying convert this into following form:

x = some expression

Comment: If $f\neq 1$, it is *just* a quartic polynomial ix $x$ that you *could* solve with radicals. If you plan to do it, you will have a lot of fun.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have been solving it for the past one hour, the process is becoming tedious, so I know i'm not doing it the right way. Can you please help?

Comment: You are wasting your time, be sure ! It is a monster if $f\neq 1$